# Multiple Roles in WordPress and CiviCRM access rights

Tags: wordpress, roles

By Default WordPress only lets users/admins set a single role per user.  This is done by a dropdown on the user's profile (in WP).

However, additional roles can be added, either by using a plugin or with custom code.  This works fine on the WP side granting the user the capabilities of all roles that they are added to.

The question is how does CiviCRM handle this?   Does it read all roles and give the user the rights of all roles?  I am testing this now, but would like any insights from others that have done this.

What have others done in this case?  I don't want to create a ton of WP roles and even though CiviCRM ACLs are available, the end user won't be able to manage that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did testing today on this and from what I can tell, when setting a second user role in WP CiviCRM will read the security settings from both roles.  It is optimistic security in that if one of the user roles has 'administer CiviCRM' and the other does not, the user can administer CiviCRM.

Comment: I guess this is a good argument for using capabilities instead ;-)

Comment: Too many caps :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a WP expert but there are settings per role via this url
wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1

which you also find via Administer > Users and Permissions > Permissions (Access Control) and then a link near the top to "WordPress Access Control"

Comment: Thanks Peter,   My question is will find all roles assigned to a user.  If so, the screen you reference will work fine.   I am testing it now but wanted to get feedback if anyone had done this before.